# How to load RDS database in EC2 window instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to connect to a RDS instance from an EC2 Instance, I connect the EC2 instance through Remote Desktop, I have RDS database endpoint url but I do not know how it works.

RDS is built into a database on Microsoft SQL Server. And this RDS instance load in windows EC2 instance, but how?

I have attached the file please check this is an EC2 instance, then how to load(connect) RDS database from EC2.

RDS endopoint database like - **abcdse-redrty.cn6kv7mpeovn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com**

Sample step or link would be appreciated.

I tried to load RDS database to EC2 window instance
[click and view window EC2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9tEW.png)

Please share any link or step.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is hard to understand. Please Edit your question to provide more information. For example, what do you mean by "load an RDS database in EC2 instance"? Are you saying that you wish to connect to an RDS database from an application that is running on an EC2 instance? Please show us the code of how you are trying to connect and also show us what error you are receiving.

Comment: Please check question again

Comment: To use a relational database, you need some client software that communicates with the database. This will either be an application you are writing, or an SQL client such as [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/). What/how are you connected to RDS?

Comment: I cant connect RDS,i have only RDS url and my requirement  is load rds in window EC2

Comment: You will need to use an SQL client to connect to RDS. Since you are using Windows, I presume you have launched a Microsoft SQL Server database. Please see: [Tutorial: Connect to and query a SQL Server instance by using SQL Server Management Studio - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I already load the RDS in the Microsoft SQL Server database, I only connect the RDS database in EC2. But can you suggest me what I can do for the next. How to upload rds  in EC2

Comment: What do you mean by "upload rds in EC2"? What are you trying to accomplish as your end-goal?

Comment: "upload means load" I open database using RDS endpoint credentials using MSSQL in EC2 instance, then does have any further process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require to connect to the RDS instance from the windows EC2 instance, then you should folllow the below mentioned steps

1. Download db client like SQLplus, workbench etc.
2. Make sure your RDS security group allows access from the EC2 instance on the required port
3. Connect to the RDS endpoint from the client installed in step 1

Comment: I open the RDS endpoint to MSSQl server in EC2 instance.it's called amazon internal DB used for RDS operations but client requirement is  upload db in EC2 instance, i can't understand how to upload in EC2.

Comment: @PromisPatel Unfortunately, we cannot understand your requirement. You can try editing your Question to provide a lot more detail.